# Url Rewriting for home page (Site)

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have to implement URL Rewriter. My site contains Single VF page which is 'Home Page'.
When I click a link from email, a salesforce site (VF page) will open which have same parameters. I want to hide to parameters by URL rewriting.

My current url is `https://xxdevbox-xxxprod.cs31.force.com/csat/?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&cval=xxx`

I want it to be like `https://xxdevbox-xxxprod.cs31.force.com/csat/cscore`

Comment: Here is the documentation on URL Rewriting: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm

Comment: I just want to rewrite current page URL.

Comment: As far as I know URL Rewriting is your only option.

Comment: @SFDCMafia Yeah I was able to mask the VF pages it directs to but not the VF page tied to Home Page itself. I don't think that masking the VF page tied to Home page is possible.